# Extra faces appear when I exit edit mode

Tags: mesh

I'm having this problem where the mesh appears to change whenever I leave edit mode. Some extra faces seem to be there but when I go back to edit mode they just disappear.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok it appears that they were just hidden, all I needed to do is press alt + H

Comment: You may want to accept this answer to mark this problem as solved